# Grouping Rows to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert this:

```
Name, YearMonth, Quantity, Rate
-------------------------------
Aaron, 201001, 10, 5
Aaron, 201002, 13, 6
Adriana, 201001, 15, 7
Adriana, 201002, 9, 8
```

to this:

```
Name, 201001-Quantity, 201001-Rate, 201002-Quantity, 201002-Rate   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Aaron, 10, 5, 13, 6
Adriana, 15, 7, 9, 8
```

I've tried to use PIVOT, but it seems like you can only pivot on 1 column

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: To get nice formatting, if you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Can you add Berta, 201003, 11, 9 to your sample data, and adjust the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when yearmonth = 201001 then quantity end) as quantity_201001,
       sum(case when yearmonth = 201001 then rate end) as rate_201001,
       sum(case when yearmonth = 201002 then quantity end) as quantity_201002,
       sum(case when yearmonth = 201002 then rate end) as rate_201002
from t
group by name;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and should work in any database.